# Servlet Exception in Netbeans

Tags: servlets, netbeans, classnotfoundexception, servletexception

**My Login form in JSP is:**

```
<form method="post" name="cust_form" id="Cust_form" action="Cust_care" onsubmit="return   Cust_check_field()">
//
</form>
```

**My Servlet is**

```
package p1;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Cust_care extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet Cust_care</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
         Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:movie_pro","sa",".");
         String cname=request.getParameter("c_name");
         st.executeUpdate();
         st.clearParameters();
           //             
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }

    catch(Exception e){}
}
```

**This is my Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web- app_2_5.xsd">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Cust_care</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>p1.Cust_care</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Cust_care</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Cust_care</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**I'm getting either error HTTP Status 404** stating that the requested resource is not available

**Or I am getting error HTTP Status 500 ** stating that java.servlet.ServletException: Wrapper could not find servlet p1.cust_care

**If anyone has solution inform**

Answer (score 0):

Does the servlet class compile?  is the processRequest() method called from a doGet() ?